# Using azure login in react native

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-active-directory

I'm currently trying to do login from azure ad using :

> react-native-azure-auth

Using this code :

```
      let tokens = await this.azureAuth.webAuth.authorize({ scope: 'offline_access profile User.ReadBasic.All Mail.Read' ,})
```

now it works fine only thing is I pass in scope "offline_access" and set it in the portal but in the response I don't get the refresh token and the scope field is missing offline_access ,

this is the example:

```
{"clientId":"69ab--04ccfbf","rawIdToken":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsxNDV0c2kwX2YwWndQYmh1WGlIMWpQ2diNUZnWHhUZVkiLCJ0aWTIzOS0zYjcxLTRmZjEtODk0Ny1mODZkGkiOiIzRlR1RkVlbG1raU9IUEVWbkNkT0FBIiwidmVyIjoiMi4wIn0.qQNLG2-kJ1CXIn8B4P8GUGimtT9WAiv5AaWhwl-Po_F14Oh8ZfAWTjaI8SQrnHfoHdbZY5_3nwjRT8Fz283Xy1bBKsgRCB75p936oO4ggPt4Mdhngzm3-xxRVvq8ysECaPlcQUFN9d6st4arly8umRypzyE6w","userId":"mail@host.com","userName":"My name","tenantId":"2b555239-3b51-4f33-8944-f81111111e0","idTokenExpireOn":1594309415000,"accessToken":"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.J9WGrG34tAs9zWF3hb5cfclWVyDSwbr082cMj1psaTqGf8SRl2Ji-ABc4mvD8AGo4nnLiH69J0M5oe9pi2041nymfqu6w_QZsg7QqPG24XnZ17SrBNOj8pyBI4i6dWL8QQM-k2cLGesKVl33h1qCo4IvKhzZFdxf6-NRIXsaP8-I-4oDCZD1n7vpSliJ5HSsp5Y3MhpF6IEzVgo4Drh2ZCwYuKLiWrEu6jG_kmXEmyOf0Fw"
,**"scope":{"scopeStr":"email mail.read user.read user.readbasic.all","scope":["email","mail.read","user.read","user.readbasic.all"]},**"expireOn":1594309417216}
```

Any ideas what i'm missing ?

Comment: Did you do every steps in this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-azure-auth#app-registration ? And the code [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-azure-auth#silent-authorization) can refresh an expired token, did it meet your requirement? Because the refresh token is used to obtain new access/refresh token pairs when the current access token expires.

Comment: I did the Authorization with user interaction
and not the second one , should i do the second one (silent) in case of expired ?

Comment: You may need to use it, the code you used uses the /authorize endpoint, as I know, you could not get refresh token from it.

Comment: this one still not returning the refresh token , and in the answered scope it still not getting offline_access

Comment: In the comment of the code `Try to get cached token or refresh an expired ones`, it can refresh an expired token, it means you don't need the refresh token, because the refresh token is used to do that.

Comment: very useful as it was the correct answer , set it as an answer so i'll mark it as true , thanks a lot !

Comment: I add it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the code below in this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-azure-auth#silent-authorization), as mentioned in the comment, it can get cached token or refresh an expired ones. No need to get the refresh token, because the refresh token is used to obtain new access/refresh token pairs when the current access token expires.

```
 try {
        // Try to get cached token or refresh an expired ones
        let tokens = await azureAuth.auth.acquireTokenSilent({scope: 'Mail.Read', userId: this.state.userId})
        if (!tokens) {
            // No cached tokens or the requested scope defines new not yet consented permissions
            // Open a window for user interaction
            tokens = await azureAuth.webAuth.authorize({scope: 'Mail.Read'})
        }
        let mails = await azureAuth.auth.msGraphRequest({token: tokens.accessToken, path: '/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages'})
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
```